# Combine CONCAT and RTRIM in WHERE SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I'm in a bit of trouble at the moment and have no idea how to fix this.

Some background info first:

I have a table with 71k records, with columns `firstname` and `lastname`. A client wants to be able to search with firstname and lastname combined.

I used this query and it works fine:

```
select * 
from `subscribers` 
where `subscribers`.`deleted_at` is null 
  and concat   (firstname," ",lastname) = 'firstname lastname'
```

except for the following problem:

some records have a trailing whitespace behind their firstname. which makes the above query not work, unless I add a second space in between firstname and lastname.

I know I have to use `RTRIM` on my `firstname`, which I tried, but doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?
I rather don't edit 71k records so they don't have a trailing space behind their names anymore...

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You can update them all in one go: `UPDATE subscribers SET firstname = RTRIM(firstname)`.  That's probably what I would do - fix the data rather than work around it...

Comment: But using the method  you already are, it would look like `concat (RTRIM(firstname)," ",lastname)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (see [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb2328/1)):

```
select * from `subscribers` 
where `subscribers`.`deleted_at` is null 
  and concat (trim(firstname)," ",trim(lastname)) LIKE 'firstname lastname';
```

Comment: I think it's more likely that the last name will also have trailing whitespace than leading whitespace, and because you changed `=` to `LIKE` that no longer works, even though it did in the OP's version.

Comment: I tried your answer in my DB and it's not working for some reason. Do I maybe need MyISAM instead of InnoDB or something?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem, apparently it was not a whitespace but actually a break in the record. I have no idea how they got that in there, but this is even worse than I expected. thank you for the help guys!